# atributos botón JS

Tags: javascript, laravel-8

tengo un boton en un datatable js con las siguientes caracteristicas.

```
{
          text: feather.icons['plus'].toSvg({ class: 'me-50 font-small-4' }) + 'Nuevo Cliente',
          className: 'create-new btn btn-primary',
          attr: {
            'data-bs-toggle': 'modal',
            'data-bs-target': '#crearcliente'
          },
```

Este al pinchar me abre un modal de bootstrap, pero quiero que me enlace o dirija a una ruta de laravel, como el href route de un  pero no se como hacerlo.

```
href="{{route('cliente.crear)}}"
```

Si me podéis ayudar os lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

para el que le haga falta, en la documentacion de datatables estaba la respuesta.

```
action: function (e, dt, node, config)
                {
                    //This will send the page to the location specified
                    window.location.href = './clientes-guardar';
                },
```

Saludos.